# Counting occurrences of elements from one list in another list

Tags: c#, linq, combinations, combinatorics

Im having two lists. Not an usual ones though.

First:

```
Combinations<string> someCombination = new Combinations<string>(someOtherList, 2);
var firstList = someCombination.ToList();
```

It returns:

```
 [0] { cy gr }
 [1] { cy ja }
 [2] { cy ka }
 [3] { cy wo }
 [4] { cy zo }
 [5] { gr ja }
 [6] { gr ka }
 [7] { gr wo }
 [8] { gr zo }
 [9] { ja ka }
[10] { ja wo }
[11] { ja zo }
[12] { ka wo }
[13] { ka zo }
[14] { wo zo }
```

Second:

```
List<List<string>> secondList = new List<List<string>>();
```

It returns:

```
 [0] { gr ch wo zo }
 [1] { zo cy gr ma }
 [2] { wo po ja cy }
 [3] { ja ka po gr }
 [4] { zo ka ja og }
 [5] { cy ja zo wo }
 [6] { gr og po ma }
 [7] { wo zo ka cy }
 [8] { gr og wo ja }
 [9] { ja ka ch wo }
```

As you can see, I'm using `Combinatorics.Collections` library. 
What I really want is to count how many times both `string` elements of `firstList` occurs in the whole `secondList` and store all those counts in the third list. Like this one:

```
List<int> occurrences = new List<int>();
```

This is an example how would this list look like, each index matches the `firstList` index:

```
 [0] 1  //because both "cy" and "gr" are contained in 1 secondList sublist(s)
 [1] 2  //because both "cy" and "ja" are contained in 2 secondList sublist(s)
 [2] 1  //et cetera..
 [3] 3
 [4] 1
 [5] 2
 [6] 1
 [7] 2
 [8] 2
 [9] 3
[10] 4
[11] 2
[12] 2
[13] 2
[14] 3
```

^If i did a mistake counting those, my bad.

I take it LINQ would probably come in handy here but I'm completely hopeless with it. Correct me if I'm mistaken. I would really appreciate the help here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  var occurrences = firstList.Select(l => secondList.Count(ss => l.All(ss.Contains))).ToList();
```

Note that this is not a good solution if these lists are big and you care about performance. In that case I would think about choosing more suitable data structures.

Comment: Frankly, i care only if it gives result and your solution really did just as i wanted. You have my deepest gratitude!

Comment: @goliatpiotr: Great! Could you accept my answer then?

Comment: Sorry, im new with this stack overflow thing. I think ive accepted now. Take care!